# Save history in iPhone webapp

Tags: iphone, web-applications, mobile, safari

I made an *iPhone Webapp* that allows an user to consult a distant database. At some point the user has to enter a code wich is quite long (about 17 digits). I would like to make the webapp remember the 3 or 5 last codes he typed.

How can I achieve this using the **cache-manifest**? (I have never used it but it looks like the right solution).

Thanks you for your attention.

Comment: Think that when your UIWebView is dealloc you lost everything and so that using cache-manifest solutions will not help you

Comment: That's not what I've read on the web. May I add that I made a **WebApp**? The kind you just add to your spring board via Safari.

Comment: Oh ! I didn't read carefully your question, sorry. You probably right as you do a webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I figured out that using cookies would be the easiest way to do it, and  hopefully cookies are actually kept for Webapps. I will struggle with the cache-manifest on an other episode.